Windows7 partition not added by grub
I recently installed Debian Stable 12.7 (from installation DVD created using iso file downloaded from official website). It is otherwise working very well.
I installed it in a logical partition. During the installation process however, the grub did not add Windows7 which I have on the first partition of the hard disk. The partition is still there and I can access all the files on that partition.
What could be the problem and how can it be solved?

Systems since 2012 are UEFI with gpt partitioning. gpt does not have logical partitions, all are primary. Windows 7 most often was installed in BIOS boot mode with very old MBR(msdos) partition, but could be UEFI/gpt with Secure boot off. Are both systems installed in UEFI boot mode or both in old BIOS/MBR mode? Note Windows 7 is obsolete and really should never be connected to Internet. UEFI & BIOS are not compatible, once you start to boot in one mode from UEFI/BIOS, you cannot switch. Or grub can only boot other installs in same boot mode.

Good information. You can put it as an answer rather than a comment only.

Systems since 2012 are UEFI with gpt partitioning. Microsoft required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode with gpt partitioning with release of Windows 8. User could install in old BIOS mode but had to use the very old MBR(msdos) partitioning. That was allowed primarily so Windows 8 could be installed to old BIOS only systems ore for update from Windows 7 that was BIOS/MBR.
gpt does not have logical partitions, all are primary and it does not have the 4 primary partition limit. Windows 7 most often was installed in BIOS boot mode with very old MBR(msdos) partition, but could be UEFI/gpt with Secure boot off.
Are both systems installed in UEFI boot mode or both in old BIOS/MBR mode?
Note Windows 7 is obsolete and really should never be connected to Internet.
UEFI & BIOS are not compatible, once you start to boot in one mode from UEFI/BIOS, you cannot switch. Or grub can only boot other installs in same boot mode.
If UEFI system, better to plan on converting all installs to UEFI with gpt partitioning. But most tools to convert from MBR to gpt will totally erase a drive, so good backups required.
